# Performance issue using IsNull function in the Select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, t-sql, isnull

I have a financial application. I have `ViewHistoricInstrumentValue` which has rows like this

```
instrument1, date1, price, grossValue, netValue
instrument2, date1, price, grossValue, netValue
...
instrument1, date2, price, grossValue, netValue
...
```

My views are complicated but the db itself is small (4000 transactions). `ViewHistoricInstrumentValue` was executed in less than 1 second before I added the next CTE to the view. After that it takes 26s. `ActualEvaluationPrice` is the price for instrumentX at dateY. If this value is missing from `HistoricPrice` table then I find the previous price for instrumentX.

```
, UsedEvaluationPriceCte AS (
SELECT *
    , isnull(ActualEvaluationPrice, 
        (select top 1 HistoricPrice.Price -- PreviousPrice
           from HistoricPrice JOIN ValidDate 
            on HistoricPrice.DateId = ValidDate.Id 
                and HistoricPrice.InstrumentId = StartingCte.InstrumentId
                and ValidDate.[Date] < StartingCte.DateValue
            order by ValidDate.[Date])) 
       as UsedEvaluationPrice
FROM StartingCte
)
```

My problem is that the execution time increased needlessly. Right now the HistoricPrice table has no missing value so ActualEvaluationPrice is never null, so the previous price should be never determined.

ViewHistoricInstrumentValue returns 1815 rows. One other mystery is that the first query takes 26s, but the second only 2s.

```
SELECT * FROM [ViewHistoricInstrumentValue]
SELECT top(2000) * FROM [ViewHistoricInstrumentValue]
```

**Appendix**

The execution plan: https://www.dropbox.com/s/5st69uhjkpd3b5y/IsNull.sqlplan?dl=0

The same plan: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rk9bK1Wiv

The view:

```
ALTER VIEW [dbo].[ViewHistoricInstrumentValue] AS 
WITH StartingCte AS (
    SELECT
        HistoricInstrumentValue.DateId
        , ValidDate.Date as DateValue
        , TransactionId
        , TransactionId AS [Row]
        , AccountId
        , AccountName
        , ViewTransaction.InstrumentId
        , ViewTransaction.InstrumentName
        , OpeningDate
        , OpeningPrice
        , Price AS ActualEvaluationPrice
        , ClosingDate
        , Amount        
        , isnull(ViewTransaction.FeeValue, 0) as FeeValue
        , HistoricInstrumentValue.Id AS Id
    FROM ViewBriefHistoricInstrumentValue as HistoricInstrumentValue 
    JOIN ValidDate on HistoricInstrumentValue.DateId = ValidDate.Id
    JOIN ViewTransaction ON ViewTransaction.Id = HistoricInstrumentValue.TransactionId
    left JOIN ViewHistoricPrice ON ViewHistoricPrice.DateId = HistoricInstrumentValue.DateId AND
        ViewHistoricPrice.InstrumentId = ViewTransaction.InstrumentId
)
, UsedEvaluationPriceCte AS (
    SELECT *
        , isnull(ActualEvaluationPrice, 
            (select top 1 HistoricPrice.Price -- PreviousPrice
               from HistoricPrice JOIN ValidDate 
                on HistoricPrice.DateId = ValidDate.Id 
                    and HistoricPrice.InstrumentId = StartingCte.InstrumentId
                    and ValidDate.[Date] < StartingCte.DateValue
                order by ValidDate.[Date])) 
           as UsedEvaluationPrice
    FROM StartingCte
)
, GrossEvaluationValueCte AS (
    SELECT *
        , Amount * UsedEvaluationPrice AS GrossEvaluationValue
        , (UsedEvaluationPrice - OpeningPrice) * Amount AS GrossCapitalGains
    FROM UsedEvaluationPriceCte
)
, CapitalGainsTaxCte AS (
    SELECT *
        , dbo.MyMax(GrossCapitalGains * 0.15, 0) AS CapitalGainsTax
    FROM GrossEvaluationValueCte    
)
, IsOpenCte AS (
    SELECT
        DateId
        , DateValue
        , TransactionId
        , [Row]
        , AccountId
        , AccountName
        , InstrumentId
        , InstrumentName
        , OpeningDate
        , OpeningPrice
        , ActualEvaluationPrice
        , UsedEvaluationPrice
        , ClosingDate
        , Amount
        , GrossEvaluationValue 
        , GrossCapitalGains
        , CapitalGainsTax 
        , FeeValue
        , GrossEvaluationValue - CapitalGainsTax - FeeValue AS NetEvaluationValue
        , GrossCapitalGains - CapitalGainsTax - FeeValue AS NetUnrealizedGains
        , CASE WHEN ClosingDate IS NULL OR DateValue < ClosingDate
        THEN CAST(1 AS BIT)
        ELSE CAST(0 AS BIT)
        END 
        AS IsOpen
        , convert(NVARCHAR, DateValue, 20) + cast([Id] AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS Temp
        , Id    
    FROM CapitalGainsTaxCte
)
Select * from IsOpenCte
```

Comment: Please show your execution plan.

Comment: Dear @DaleK    I have added the execution plan but I do not know if it helps because it is just too complicated (for me at least).

Comment: Dear @DaleK I shared the plan with brentozar also.

Comment: Do you have to use a view? I would suggest instead of using a CTE, materialising the intermediate results into a temp table and then selecting from that. By splitting your query like this you will get two simpler query plans instead of one massive complex plan.

Comment: @DaleK   If ViewTransaction is put into a temp table then the time is less then 1s. In that case the execution plan of ViewHistoricInstrumentValue  is more clear: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=S1F-gebsw     For me it seems that if no temp table is used then a lot of unneeded calculation is carried out.

Comment: with a CTE SQL Server builds a single execution plan for the entire query, which is a pretty complex query (often the case with CTEs). The more complex the execution plan, the harder it can be for SQL Server to get it right. By using a temp table to materialise the results you split the process into two execution plans, each significantly simpler than the whole. I have certainly found this necessary in many CTE cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea what your query is supposed to be doing.  But this process:

> ActualEvaluationPrice is the price for instrumentX at dateY. If this value is missing from HistoricPrice table then I find the previous price for instrumentX.

is handled easily with `lag()`:

```
select vhiv.*
       coalesce(vhiv.ActualEvaluationPrice,
                lag(vhiv.ActualEvaluationPrice) over (partition by vhiv.InstrumentId order by DateValue)
               ) as UsedEvaluationPrice
from ViewHistoricInstrumentValue vhiv;
```

Note:  If you need to filter out certain dates by joining to `ValidDates`, you can include the `JOIN` in the query.  However, that is not part of the problem statement.

Comment: Hi @Gordon Linoff ! It took me some time but I understood your suggestion. This helped me to go one step further. It turned out that the problem is not with determining the previous price. If I skip this part and only list the result of the first cte (`StartingCte`) then it is finished at once. If I do the same but now with `order by DateId` then 26s second is needed, if `order by Id` is used then it is again 0 sec. This is very strange. I know it is a different question but do you any idea?